# How to order results by time in KDB+

Tags: kdb

I am doing a simple select query similar to below,

select date, time, price, volume from trades where sym=`AAPL.

I would like to order the return results by the time column, but after reading the docs and trying to do

select[>time]  date, time, price, volume from trades where sym=`AAPL.

I get an error.

Can someone advise?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you querying a partitioned or splayed database?

If so, from code.kx.com:
"This construct works on in-memory tables but not on memory-mapped tables loaded from splayed or partitioned files"

Therefore two ways to sort:

```
q)t1:select[<time] from select date,time,sym,price from trade where date=last date,sym=`AAPL
q)t2:`time xasc select date,time,sym,price from trade where date=last date,sym=`AAPL
q)t1~t2
1b
```